# "zsh: command not found: expo" despite it being installed

Tags: ios, bash, react-native, expo, zsh

I recently bought MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020 i5) and downloaded expo globally, now the problem which i am facing is it keeps saying expo command not found despite it being installed.
I have tried various soultions such as:

1. https://forums.expo.io/t/expo-cli-looks-installed-but-expo-command-not-found/14535
   (NOTE: The newer version of macOS does not have .bash_profile anymore and has .zprofile instead)
   [image]
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkqsLRDnqlA

But none of the solution works.

However, to check if it actually works, I cloned one of my projects from work and just changed the script from package.json and runned it from NPM SCRIPT and it does fire up (so it's just the command line that shows command not found and doesn't allow me to init the project and none of the solutions works from the google somehow.

[image]

Comment: You may need to add `expo` to your PATH variable. You can create .bash_profile if it isn't already present. If you're using Zsh as your shell, you can create the entry in .zprofile or .zshrc also.

Comment: I see that you are using ZSH , can you try the comamand in normal terminal ?

Comment: try using sudo expo --version to check whether it is working or not ? maybe you might have done or replaced something wrong during installation.